# CF Website Migration

Tags: website, coldfusion, migration, live-migration

I am a System admin assigned the task of migrating a couple of Cold Fusion websites from a 2003 Server(SQLSERVER 2005) to 2012 Server(SQLSERVER 2008).
I have the least idea or even a list of precautions to be considered beforehand.
Could anyone come up with a link or a doc for a scenario that suites this?

I have come across a [doc](http://www.jasonholden.com/blog/index.cfm/2009/8/7/Coldfusion-8-and-9-on-Windows-Server-2003-Server-2008-Vista-and-Windows-7-x86-and-x64) that shows how to install CF on a Server 2008/2003, but not on how to move the websites or with the DB connection.

I have'nt ever been on such a task- i have very little experience on IIS and SQL as well. :(

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have too much issue, you main issue will be ensuring configurations are correct, any customized setting in coldfusion administrator, any stored procedures or special database configurations etc. each is server migration is unique in that way. It's really hard to gauge what could go wrong.

Coldfusion will let you package a CAR file to export it's settings, depending on your version of cf, compatability might be an issue. If it isn't too many you could do it manually.

My recommendation is you move the website files first and establish a connection to the old database. Once that's working transfer the database and repoint the datasource to the new database.

Comment: thanks. I have a green light from the dev team. I did not know about the settings export- spcl thanks. I will be back- when im stuck ;)